# How to save variable in file in crontab

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I have some task in cron scheduler:

```
40 07 * * * value=$(curl -d '{"query":"java-middle", "turnOff":true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/explorer)
```

- The **Value** accept a json in string format
- how to save a **value** (or result of curl command) in file and get them in future tasks?

Comment: Rather than asking `cron` to interpret `bash` expressions, you should write a `bash` script to accomplish your task, and call that `bash` script from your `crontab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

- in this case, command cannot to assign value to variable (**value** in my example) and simultaneously save value in file. Than must erase string **value=$**
- for save result in file just adds **>filename**

> 40 07 * * * curl -d '{"query":"java-middle", "turnOff":true}' -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST
>   http://localhost:8080/explorer >/path/filename

Comment: `curl` also has an option to specify the output file and an option to silence it (i.e. to suppress the progress bars and such). Try `curl ... -s -o /path/filename`.